# How to obtain a list sorted in a pyramidal way using SQL Orm Lite?

Tags: c#, list, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, sortedlist

One of our clients solicited us to display the scores from a user's friends list following the  next criteria:

If my score is 1100, I need to get a list of my friends sorted by those who are closest to me in score first. If my friends are Gonzalo 1250, Marilda 1100 and Marco 950, the list should be ordered as follows:

Marilda 1100
Gonzalo 1250 
Marco 950

Since Marilda and me have the same score, the difference in score is 0, so she is closest to me. Gonzalo is 150 points away from me, just like Marco is, but Gonzalo's score is higher than Marco, so he comes first, then Marco.

We spent some time thinking how to perform this query with no clue so far, we are using [Service Stack](https://servicestack.net/) free version, which makes all of its queries with [SQL Orm Lite](http://ormlite.com/data_types.shtml).

Comment: Are you having trouble coming up with the algorithm, or are you having trouble coming up with the implementation?  Both seem straightforward. Some variation of: select the results, compute the ABS of the difference, and also assign a value based on whether the score is higher (0) or lower (1).  Then sort the results first by ABS of the difference (ascending), then on the higher/lower field (ascending)

Comment: We didn't considered the use of a variable to determine the difference, we have to try and implement that, what worries us the most is the performance of this query and how it would affect the time response from the API. We'll let you know how it worked for us, meanwhile you should put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @UrielArvizu - just use a simple SQL query to get the list of friends and scores, then sort the data in C# and return it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is probably some variation of:

```
select UserName, ABS(Score - @MyScore) as ScoreDelta, Score > @MyScore ? 0 : 1 as HigherOrLower
from ScoreTable
order by ScoreDelta, HigherOrLower
```

Where UserName and Score are columns in the ScoreTable.  MyScore is a scalar value.

Most of the entries will be ranked based on their difference from your score.  If there's a tie (Like Gonzalo and Marco) then the one that's higher than your score will be sorted first.

Sorry - I don't think the SQL isn't exactly right (syntax) - It's been a few years since I've touched a database.  I'm fairly certain that the ternary conditional operator in the select statement isn't valid SQL - but you get the idea

Alternatively, if you have user/score pairs from the database and want to sort in the application then:

```
public class UserScore
{
     public string Name { get; private set; }
     public int Score { get; private set; }
     //. . .
}

var sortedScores = from userScore in MyFriendScores
                   orderby Math.Abs(userScore.Score - myScore), userScore.Score > myScore ? -1 : +1
                   select userScore;
```

or

```
var sortedScores = MyFriendScores
                     .OrderBy(o => Math.Abs(o.Score - myScore))
                     .ThenBy(o => o.Score > myScore ? -1 : +1);
```

The concept is identical - sort first on the ABS of the difference, then as a tie-breaker sort on whether it's higher or lower than your score.